# How many times will "statement" be executed?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Suppose we have the following:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    for(int j = i; j <= n; ++j)
        //statement

for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    for(int j = i; j <= n; ++j)
        for(int k = j; k <= n; ++k)
            //statement
```

In either case, is there a straightforward way to know how many times "statement" will be executed?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You are effectively computing

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n 1 = \sum_{i=1}^n (n-i+1) = n(n+1) - \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

In this case there's an easy geometric way of visualizing the sum: you're counting the number of entries in a $n\times n$ matrix lying on or below the diagonal.

Similarly

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \sum_{k=j}^n &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n (n-j+1)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\left[\sum_{j=i}^n(n+1) - \sum_{j=i}^nj\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\left[(n-i+1)(n+1) - \sum_{j=i}^nj\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\left[(n-i+1)(n+1) - \left(\sum_{j=1}^n j-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j\right)\right]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[(n-i+1)(n+1) - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{i(i-1)}{2}\right]\\
&= n(n+1)^2 - \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2} - \frac{n(n+1)^2}{2} - \frac{n(n+1)}{4} + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}\\
&=\frac{n(n^2+3n+2)}{6}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you elaborate on the steps in the triple summation?  Namely, how we arrive at this:

$= \sum_{i=1}^n\left[(n-i+1)(n+1) - \sum_{j=i}^nj\right]\\$

and this:

$=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[(n-i+1)(n+1) - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{i(i-1)}{2}\right]\\$

Comment: I've added some extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

more short answer would be C(n+2,3) + C(n+1,2) by fundamental principles of counting C(n+the number of loop-1,the number of loop)